# Azure login for Angular App in iFrame of another Angular App

Tags: angular, azure, iframe, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have two separate angular apps and both are enabled with Azure AD login. When I access both apps separately in the tab, they work fine, they redirect and get the token and all is good.

I now want to have Angular 1 as a Parent and Angular 2 as a child as one of the tabs in the parent application.

For this, we have control of Azure configuration and I can define both angular apps within the same tenant. ( not sure, right term as I am not much familiar with Azure portal working.)

Both applications are using the MSAL library to provide clientID, authority, etc to redirect and get the token.

When a user logs into the parent application via a redirect that is fine but I do not want users to log in to the child app again and the flow should be smooth.

How do I achieve this? Is it all taken care of by the azure configuration so that the child app will not go for authentication again? In this case, child app will return the same token as the parent application token? Is it possible to achieve?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single sign-on in Azure Active Directory to meet your requirement.Single sign-on is an authentication method that allows users to sign in using one set of credentials to multiple independent software systems. Using SSO means a user doesn't have to sign in to every application they use..

Please check this for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-setup-sso